# Link to candidate you voted for on election page not completely working

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, election, accessibility

In the "Your final votes" section of election pages, when you hover over the name of a candidate you voted for, the mouse pointer seems to suggest you can click on it, but nothing happens. Only the avatar takes you to the user's profile page.

[image]

Comment: I think it means you can *drag* it, but not 100% sure, need to see it in action.

Comment: @shadow: You can't drag it now, because the election is over. So clicking the name element and/or the avatar should lead you to the user's profile page

Comment: @Justin well, this is still the same element, with same CSS, likely.

Comment: Wait. You really trusted that user to be a good moderator?

Comment: @rene yeah I did ... back then.